# Tcl/Tk script to make a button that switches colour when clicked?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Just making a really simple Tcl/Tk program to learn, but I'm having a little trouble.

I need to make a button switch colours when clicked, so it will start red, when clicked it will turn green, and if clicked again will go back to red.

I have got it changing from red to green, but I don't know how to make it go back the other way.
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very hard (except on OSX, where this sort of thing is *directly* against platform UI guidelines) you just need to use a suitable callback:

```
button .b -background red -command [list toggleTheButton .b]
set state(.b) 1
proc toggleTheButton w {
    global state
    if {$state($w)} {
        $w configure -background green
    } else {
        $w configure -background red
    }
    set state($w) [expr {!$state($w)}]
}
```

Consider using a `checkbutton` instead when you need toggling, as it will be much more rapidly understood by the users.

Comment: Note that `toggleTheButton` will work with as many buttons as you want. Just make the button as shown (but with a different name, of course) and initialize the state.

Comment: Thanks heaps. Yeah, I understand the problems with doing it this way, but this is how it has to be done for this particular app.